# Callback functions that reference each other? Nested if statements? Need guidance

Tags: callback, nested

first time long time here.
I just started programming in javascript recently, I'm running into a question of design.

I have some working code that:
1. Waits for specific input from the serial port,
2. When input is found it moves to the next function.
3. The next function sends a command(s) over the serial port and then waits for input again.

Now I have 9 functions defined as stepone() steptwo() etc.... There has to be a better way to do this. Each function is the same except with different variables for input and output desired.

However, I do not want the program to skip steps. It needs to wait for the correct serial input before sending the next command.

I've tried using callback functions referencing each other, it just seems...wrong?
Also, it doesn't work. It doesn't wait for the right input before sending commands.

```
    var waitforinput = function(input, regex, callback)
    {
        if (regex.search != -1)
            callback();
    };

    var sendcommand = function(command,callback)
    {
        port.writeline(command);
        if (callback)
            callback();
    };

    var connect = function()
    {
        var int = setInterval(function()
        {
            waitforinput(input, "Please choose:", function()
            {
                sendcommand("1", function()
                {
                    waitforinput(input, "You choosed", function()
                    {
                        sendcommand("saveenv 1");
                    });
                });
            });
        },50);
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using switch() with cases and keeping track of a variable called step:

```
    step = 1;
    switch(step)
    {
    case 1:
        if (inputbuffer.search('Please choose') !== -1)
        {
            if (!waitdisplaystarted)
            {
                waitdisplaystarted = true;
                waitint = setInterval(showwait,1000);
            }
            window.$("#instructions").hide();
            window.$("#status").html("Step 1: Choosing boot option.");
            SELF.sendserialcommand("1");
            step = 2;
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        if (inputbuffer.search('You choosed 1') !== -1)
        {
            SELF.sendserialcommand('setenv bootargs "board=ALFA console=ttyATH0,115200 rootfstype=squashfs,jffs2 noinitrd"\r');
            setTimeout(function(){SELF.sendserialcommand('saveenv\r');}, 50);
            window.$("#status").html("Step 2: Transferring new kernel.");
            setTimeout(function(){SELF.sendserialcommand('tftp 0x80600000 kernel.bin\r');}, 2000);
            step = 3;
        }
        break;
    case 3:
        if (inputbuffer.search('Bytes transferred = ' + 878938) !== -1)
        {
            window.$("#status").html("Step 3: Erasing old kernel.");
            SELF.sendserialcommand('erase 0x9f650000 +0x190000\r');
            step = 'finished';
        }
    }
```